# Foreach comma separated item

Tags: python, arrays, list, foreach, pygtk

I'm creating my first Python application (PyGTK) and will use a conf file. In that will I will have a section containing a general section with the option of the other sections like this:

```
[profile]
shares = share1, share2, abc234, kallebengtsson

[share1]
username = daniel
```

I want to separate that "shares" option and do a foreach of them:

```
foreach shares:
 print username
```

How would I do that? In PHP I would do this as an array, but I'm uncertain about Python.

I'm using ConfigParser using this guide: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/ConfigParser/

And this is my code: https://github.com/danielholm/BareShare/blob/master/bareshare.py

Comment: I would look at the documentation on strings and for loops :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
shares = parser.get('profile', 'shares')
for share in shares.split(', ')
    username = parser.get(share, 'username')
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now:
https://github.com/danielholm/BareShare/commit/3cc0dc8f9dbb5298df21e96ddec52cfadc328136

Answer (score 4):

```
for username in shares.split(', '):
  print username
```